# bind dropdownlist according to the header of the gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdownlist and the gridview and I want to bind the dropdownlist according to the header of the grid view

eg.

If I have a grid view header like

```
  A     B       C        D   edit    delete
```

Then the dropdown should have values like

```
A
B
C
D
```

Comment: Post some code to see what you are working with. It will help users to understand better and help you out

Comment: As far i understand, Do you want to bind the DropDownList to the selected Gridview element?

Comment: i want to bind the dropdown accourding to the number of the fields in the gridview.
my overall motive is, i have a text box in which the user can enter enything and from the dropdown he select for which he wants to filter out and the grid view will show the results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like below

```
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Columns.Count ; i++)
    {
        list.Add(GridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText);
    }
    DropDownList1.DataSource = list;
```